# Wiring Help in a Camper/Tiny Home

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

So, my father-in-law just recently bought a camper/trailer and the bathroom light was busted. He disconnected all power to the trailer, removed the busted light, and then ordered a new one off of eBay. The new one didn't come with a wiring diagram and he's older, so he doesn't remember how the previous light was wired up.

Currently, out of the ceiling, we have two lines, each with one white wire and one black/white wire (so two white and two black/white out of the ceiling, in two different lines). The light itself has one black wire and two white wires and the light has a switch on it. There's a fan to the left of the light/lightbox and it looks like one of the wires coming out of the ceiling goes to that. The fan has its own switch, so I don't think the switch from the light controls it.

Any idea what I should do here?

Comment: Is it a camper or a tiny house?  Notwithstanding the desire to sound cool, they are very, very different things.  Not least, one is battery 12V and the other is mains 120V.

Comment: with 3 wires of different polarity, a good guess is that all the blacks get connected and all the whites get connected; other topologies don't make a lot of sense for that combo.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried wiring all 3 together, of the same color, and it didn't work. Then we found out my father-in-law hadn't tightened the connector to the battery. So, we have everything working now. Thanks again!